# Recording screen with ffmpeg & vaapi

Tags: linux, debian, video, ffmpeg, xorg

I got Debian 9 and stock Xorg drivers.
Today i'm trying record my screen with ffmpeg & vaapi, but I have some problems.

I want to record all screen with max FPS.
`xrandr` setting is: 1920x1080 60.00*+

My `ffmpeg` parameters are:
`./ffmpeg -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -r 60 -i :0 -vf 'format=yuv444p,hwupload' -c:v h264_vaapi output.mp4`

When I record the video with that command, the output file has many problems, frame rate problem, color problem, and other weird things.

My example output video from that command (rerendered with `./ffmpeg -i output.mp4 asd.mp4` for lower file size, quality don't have much difference):

[You can find it here at Google.Drive]
(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jNH...47NChORAD/view)

Here is an [sample frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH9t9.png) from this video.

How can I fix the screen record?

Some other small informations on my system:

`-Desktop
-OS: Debian 9 amd64
-Cpu: amd a10 7890k
-Gpu: no external gpu`

`~$ uname -a
Linux debian 4.9.0-7-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u2 (2018-08-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`~$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/radeonsi_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.3)
vainfo: Driver version: mesa gallium vaapi
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
VAProfileMPEG2Simple :  VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileMPEG2Main :    VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Simple :    VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Main :  VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileVC1Advanced :  VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline:   VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline:   VAEntrypointEncSlice
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointEncSlice
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointVLD
VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointEncSlice
VAProfileNone : VAEntrypointVideoProc`